# 3rd party dependency in travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I'm developing an open source project containing a number of optimization tools. I've uploaded the project to github and I would like to automatically run the test suite every time someone submits a pull request. To this extend I was planning on using travis-ci. Problem is that the test suite depends on a 3rd party solver (IBM cplex).

To run the test suite locally on my computer, I would do the following:

1. Download and install solver IBM Cplex
2. Install cplex.jar in my local maven repository: `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=cplex -DartifactId=cplex -Dversion=12.6.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/opt/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/lib/cplex.jar`
3. Set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to point to the solver's native libraries: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
4. Compile/run the test suite.

Problems:

- Cplex is not open source; I don't want to upload it to my github repository. In addition, its unpacked size is quite big (1GB).

Is there a way to uploaded the necessary solver files to travis-ci without making them publicly available? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703491/how-can-i-add-a-3rd-party-jar-to-my-travis-ci-maven-build) stack overflow question describes how I could get my cplex.jar into travis, but as far as I can tell I would have to put the jar on some webserver and add a clearly readable link to in in the .travis.yml file.

Even if I manage to get cplex.jar into travis, how do I get the native libraries there as well? Their size is quite big, so it would be undesirable if travis has to download these libraries every time it has to perform a build. Furthermore, I don't want to make these libraries available to anyone but the travis test system.

If it turns out that the above is not possible. Is there another CI system, perhaps one that I can run on a private server, that could do this and run whenever a pull-request is submitted through github?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Travis [file encryption](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/). You would still need to add the (albeit) encrypted `cplex.jar` to your git repository, but at least it wouldn't be public. I can see why this would not be ideal in your type of situation but since you didn't mention it, I wrote this answer just in case.

Alternatively, you could also store the `cplex.jar` on your own server, and then store the URL in an [encrypted environment variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/).